# div overlay on textarea to catch mouse clicks

Tags: jquery

I have a textarea within a div.
I want to be able to click on the overlay.
But what happens is the textarea catches the click as well as the div.

```
<div id="d" name="d"><textarea id="ta" name="ta">my text</textarea></div>

<script type="text/javascript">
$('#d').click(function(){alert("clicked on div");)};
$('#ta').click(function(){alert("clicked on textarea");)};
</script>
```

I just want the div alert to fire, and not the textarea.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First permuting the order of the brackets at the end to prevent javascript errors:

```
$('#d').click(function(){alert("clicked on div");});
$('#ta').click(function(){alert("clicked on textarea");});
```

Then I get both alerts, see [this example](http://jsfiddle.net/adqck/).

=== UPDATE ===

The event bubbles from the upper dom element down to the lowest (if you don't prevent bubbling). So you can stop bubbling the event after the `textarea`, but you can't prevent to get it in the `div` and not in the `textarea`. You have to change the order of the html elements (`div`and `textarea`) and then add a `return false;` at the end of the `div` click handler or add an `event.stopPropagation();`. Also see my [updated example](http://jsfiddle.net/adqck/2/) or my [next example](http://jsfiddle.net/adqck/3/).